# Convert AddToTable methods in EntityFramework to Table.Add() method

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

Previously I was using object context for my application. So I was using AddToTable() methods like

```
context.AddToTable(entity);
```

but now I am using DbContext and I have to use the Add method like

```
context.Table.Add(entity);
```

Now I'm having the older method called more than 300 times. So I was wondering is there any solution to change the methods solution wide.

Comment: You could use extension methods.

Comment: @germi Could you please explain how to use it.. cause AddToTable methods are different for different table. In AddToTable "Table" is the name of the table.

Comment: Do you have any actual code examples of the expected input/output?

Comment: @rvalvik 

input -> dataEntity.AddTosupp_status(suppStatus);
output -> dataEntity.supp_status.Add(suppStatus);

but supp_status is the table name so it'll be different for different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use you Regex search and replace for this, something along these lines might do the job.

Given that you don't have any other methods named `AddToX(` you could use the following regex:
`\.AddTo([^(]+)\(`

This would match `.AddToX(` then you replace with `.\1.Add(` where `\1` is a back-reference, so it might be `$1` depending on your flavor of regex.

That would transform `.AddToX(` into `.X.Add(`.

How you would process your code with the regex I can't answer so that would only be half the puzzle, many IDE's have project wide search and replace I guess.

Regardless, make backups before you do anything of this nature.

Comment: Thank you very much.. $1 works for me with visualstudio find and replace tool.